# Renaming a user and cross-account policy behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When renaming a user that is referenced on a same account S3 bucket policy as a principal I know that it automatically updates the user reference on the bucket policy to the new user-name per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_manage.html). However, when the user from Account A is being used on another Account in a bucket policy, does it also automatically update it on the other account?

AWS Account A -> User A -> S3 Bucket with policy granting permissions to User A

AWS Account B -> S3 Bucket with policy granting permissions to User A

AWS Account A -> Renames User A to User A2

AWS Account A -> Bucket policy is updated to A2 (confirmed during testing)

AWS Account B -> Bucket with policy granting permissions to User A or User A2 now?

[User renaming documentation section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yoir.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AWS Account B -> Bucket with policy granting permissions to User A or User A2 now?

Yes, it **will be changed** to A2. I **verified** it using two accounts.